# flutterfire_cli not working Unhandled exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 91, character 1)

Tags: database, flutter, firebase

Actually I wanted to make an flutter app and I wanted to connect it to the firebase so I installed firebase tools by `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Then I logged in by this command `firebase login`

After that I activated the flutter_cli package in the project root folder by `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli` and I put the path in the system variables in the `PATH` variable like that `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin`

Finally I wanted to configure the firebase so I ran `flutterfire configure` and I choosed my project on firebase and choosed the platforms that I want to add, here the error appears

Image Of The Error

[image]

**Note: The line number and the character number in the error changes every time the error appears**

Version Details

**Flutter 3.10.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git 

Framework • revision 9cd3d0d9ff (7 days ago) • 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700 

Engine • revision 90fa3ae28z 

Tools • Dart 3.0.2 • DevTools 2.23.1**

**OS: Windows 11**

I'll be so happy with your help!